# Cannot format Lenovo Notebook to Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, formatting, lenovo-laptop, windows-installation

I have a Lenovo B430 notebook, which I'm trying to format to Windows XP SP3 Professional, 'cause of some driver problems in Windows 7.

The notebook boot the CD fine, but when try to show the screen where I choose how to format gives me this screen though:

[image]

Also I record the whole thing which you can watch it here:[video](http://youtu.be/eDK6b3cu6tg)

What do I have to do to format this notebook ?

Comment: You do understand the driver problem will likely exists with Windows XP also right?  Looking at the `BSOD` in question it looks a hardware conflict.  It looks like the hdd is to blame.  Furthermore `Lenovo B430` has drivers for Windows 8 which means, it very likely, the device DOES NOT support Windows XP and even comes with Windows 7 preinstalled.

Comment: Why don't you just solve the driver problem?

Comment: @Ramhound when you said that this device does not support Windows XP you mean that I cannot install it in this notebook ? Where did you get this info ? About the driver problem it would be very expensive, 'cause the software which is given me this trouble works only in XP.

Comment: http://www.computing.net/howtos/show/howto-install-windows-xp-to-sata-hard-drive/594.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to set to `compatibility` mode the SATA drivers and set then back when finish my formatting.

[image]
[image]